# Subtract 2 measures as Grand Total in SSAS Cube Browser

Tags: aggregate-functions, ssas, mdx, dimensions, cube

I guess it's a common and basic issue. I'm trying to get the "net value" of a measure depending on a dimension. Let me explain..

I have a fact table *factTicket* and a dimension called *Operation* who have 2 values: Opened and Closed. The goal is to get the number of ticket opened and closed for each month.
In the Cube Browser, I have a *Distinct Count Measure* of the *TicketID* according to the Operation dimension, but I would like the Grand Total to be **Opened minus Closed** instead of **Opened + Closed**

The factTable has a record with the date for every opened ticket, and a second record is added when the ticket is closed (So a Ticket can only have a maximum of 2 records in the fact table)

Is it possible ? I can't find a way to do it.. Maybe the Operation Dimension is a bad idea and I should have 1 record per ticket, with an OpenedDate and ClosedDate field ? I don't believe it will fixe the probleme since Distinct Count always return positive value, so the Grand Total will still be Opened + Closed.

Any ideas is welcome !
Thx

Comment: I don't know if i'm on the good track, but i've been able to alter the measure with the Scope() function:

SCOPE([Dim Operation].[OpenClose].&[CLOSE], [Measures].[TicketCount]);
    THIS = [Measures].[TicketCount] * -1;
END SCOPE;

The DistinctCount measure is now negative, but the Grand Total seems to ignore the alteration ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope function is what I needed:

```
SCOPE([Dim Operation].[OpenClose].[All], [Measures].[TicketCount]);
THIS = [Dim Operation].[OpenClose].&[OPEN] - [Dim Operation].[OpenClose].&[CLOSE]
END SCOPE;
```